# Handling validation errors using `fluent-json-schema` in Fastify

Tags: fastify

I'm using `fluent-json-schema` for validating requests. Having the following schema:

```js
const gwoogl = S.object()
    .prop('title_desc', S.string()/*.allow('')*/.minLength(3).maxLength(100))
    .prop('exact', S.boolean().default(false))
    .prop('div_q', S.string()/*.allow('')*/.minLength(3).maxLength(40))
    .prop('since', S.string().format(S.FORMATS.DATE_TIME))
    .prop('section', S.string().enum(['donations', 'skills']))
const gwooglSchema = {
    body: gwoogl,
}
```

Showing it where it is consumed is as the following (so I think the format is correct):

```js
{"level":50,"time":1643319721118,"pid":9712,"hostname":"WIN-E91D14FS6F4","body":{"isFluentSchema":true,"isFluentJSONSchema":true}}
```

The problem is that I can't see how I handle errors, furthermore it seems schema is not taken into account at all, I can for instance `POST { title_desc: 'a' }` which must not validate.

```js
fastify.post('/gwoogl', { gwooglSchema }, async (req, reply) => {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad I should have passed: `{ schema: gwooglSchema }`